# 日(ひ) は大昔からdayの意味持っていたのか

Tags: usage, kanji, etymology, history, wago-and-kango

日本は漢人に接触し漢字と漢語を輸入した前に大和言葉はもう存在していたから、きっとその時にもうdayを指す語はもうあった。現代の視点から見ると、和語のdayの意味の言葉は「日(ひ)」なんですけど(例えば その日、あの日、出会った日)、これも漢語の影響なんですか？

詳細に言うと、昔の大和言葉の一日を指す語は「日(か)」だったと思うのは正しいですか。一ヶ月の中の日付も(二日ふつ**か**、三日みっ**か**等)、暦(こよみ、辞書によってかよみの転、日読みの意)もdayは「か」で現す。

以下は自分の憶測です。大和言葉の「ひ」は元々「火(ひ)」を指す語で、その意味を広めて空にある大きい火の玉「太陽」も指すことができるようになってきました。訓読みが成り立つ時、「日」の字は太陽の意味があるので「ひ」の訓に関連された。なのに、漢語でsunとdayは区別されなく全部「日」の字で書くので(発音も同じ)、それに影響され、和語の「ひ」はdayの意味にもどんどん染まった。

それは正しいですか。でなければ正しい語源はなんでしょうか。

Comment: [この古語辞典](https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%B2)では昼間の意味の用例で古事記を挙げているので、（これが妥当だと考える限り）厳密な答えを見つけるのは難しいのではないかと思います。

Comment: 件名で聞いていることと本文中で聞いていることが違うように見えますが、気のせいですか。件名に関しては「ひる」自体が「ひ」と関係していたと思います。day という概念については分かりませんが、moon も month も「つき」なので、「ひ」も漢語の影響なしで二つの概念が繋がったとしても不思議ではない気がします。

Comment: @aguijonazo すみません、件名を編集しました。今でも使われてる和語の日付の数え方に「日」は「か」で読むのが気になっただけでした。少し考えて以上の結論を得ました。

Comment: 「大和言葉の「ひ」は元々「火(ひ)」を指す語で、その意味を広めて空にある大きい火の玉「太陽」も指すことができるようになってきました。」この部分に関しては明確に違うということができます。10世紀頃までは[日（いわゆるヒ甲）と火（ヒ乙）は異なる音](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8A%E4%BB%A3%E7%89%B9%E6%AE%8A%E4%BB%AE%E5%90%8D%E9%81%A3#%E4%B8%87%E8%91%89%E4%BB%AE%E5%90%8D)でした。日はpi、火はpuiのような発音だったと推測されています。

Comment: Ya, as @broccoliforest notes, these were phonemically different words in the Old Japanese stage of the language. 火 still manifests with a different monophthong in older compounds, such as [炎]{ほのお} (originally [火の穂]{ほのほ}), [火影]{ほかげ}, etc. By one analysis, nouns that exhibit this 被覆形・露出形 vowel dichotomy may reflect an ancient fusional morpheme (some kind of suffix?), or perhaps an integral phoneme that was subject to deletion in compounds. At any rate, we know that the `/i/` in 火 was previously qualitatively different from the `/i/` in 日, and that these two were separate words phonetically.